# is there a drush command to call a method from a custom class?

Tags: class, object, drupal, drush

Is there a way to call methods from custom classes using drush? In the same vein, is there a way to instantiate the objects from drupal custom classes in the command line (and have all the drupal_specific functionality that was used in the class preserved)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Eric, you will need to write your own custom drush command to satisfy this.  And it might even be helpful to others if you can make it dynamic enough. Check out this link: http://drush.ws/docs/commands.html

Answer (score 5):

There are `drush php-eval` (see `drush help php-eval`) and `drush php-script` (see `drush help php-script`) to run some php code from within Drupal environment.

But you have to initialize or load your custom objects yourself inside your php code.

An example:

```
drush @mysitealias php-eval '$nid = 85; $n = node_load($nid); var_export($n);'
```

Answer (score 0):

To Create Custom Drush Commands This Is For Drupal 7:-
follow the instruction provided in http://internetdevels.com/blog/creating-custom-drush-commands

Comment: another helpful answer. I love stackoverflow!